# How to remove the clickable nature of rows in flutter Data Table class?

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app where I just want to display data in the table, I don't want the rows to be clickable, but by default they are clickable. How can I turn it off?

```dart
DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Age',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Role',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

This is the sample code from the flutter website.

Comment: I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution?

Comment: @uyhaW I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the splash effect of rows by setting both splashColor and highlightColor to transparent in MaterialApp theme as bellow:

```
  return MaterialApp(

  title: 'Flutter Demo',

  theme: ThemeData(

    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  );
```

That disables tap splash effet.

Comment: Setting theme like this is only solving half problem, when we click on rows it is making tap sounds. Is there any alternative way where we can remove the clickable feature instead of turning splash color to transparent?

Comment: Maybe in your case, it's better to try other layouts like Table or GridView instead of DataTable class.